# Force Internet Explorer to ignore IE=EmulateIE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, ie-compatibility-mode

I'm working with Blackboard 9.1 SP13 and by the default the platform has the typical:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

But i want Internet Explorer >8 to ignore this meta tag in just one page because it is not working properly.

I can't change the meta tag since it is hardcoded in the platform and I can't customize this feature (my boss doesn't allow me to change de .vm template, it is not an option).

¿Is there a way I can tell Internet Explorr >8 to ignore this meta in the page with a code inside the page? Some kind of Javascript or something...

Thanks in advance

Comment: In case someone is still interested, Blackboard SP13 doesn't have this problem anymore. There was a problem with the latest security update in Internet Explorer 11, so Blackboard had to distribute a patch that eliminates <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />. So, for my case, this is not a problem anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try having the server send the equivalent header with a new value:

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
```

In general, headers from the server override headers set in HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't work... "If both of these instructions are sent, the developer's preference (meta element) takes precedence over the web server setting (HTTP header)." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275(v=vs.85).aspx